# Categorical way of making monos commute

Tags: category-theory, model-categories, limits-colimits, monomorphisms

Is there a categorical way (in terms of diagrams, limits, lifting properties etc) to formulate the requirement that for every pair of monos $f,g:C \to D$ there should be an endomorphism $h:D \to D$, s.t. $h\circ f = g$? I found a couple of specific monos (regular, strict,strong,orthogonal..) but nothing seems to fit for my problem..

Comment: Well.. Isn't what you wrote already in terms of category theory? Sets and Vector spaces are examples. Do you have in mind any other examples?

Comment: Technically yes, but I thought that there is maybe a more general concept "explaining" this typical property...

Comment: Also, "commute" is not the term I'd use for this either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a condition on monomorphisms at all; as formulated it's a condition on $C$ and $D$. Here is the most closely related thing I know.

A topological space $X$ is sometimes said to be *homogeneous* if for every $x, y \in X$ there is a homeomorphism $f : X \to X$ such that $f(x) = y$. This is the special case of your situation in $\text{Top}$ where $C$ is a point and $h$ is required to be an isomorphism. Most spaces are not homogeneous but, for example, all connected manifolds without boundary are.

In general this condition seems hard to satisfy. I don't expect there's anything particularly nice to say about it.

Comment: Okay thx! At least now I have a name for such categories ;)

Comment: @Bipolar: I think that's a bad term to use for the *category*. I'm explicitly using it for $D$, with a fixed choice of $C$, and with a restriction on $h$.